# Data studio filtering out empty dimensions from report automatically?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a dataset that is a query pointed at bigquery, the dataset has X number of rows being returned. However when i drag the columns onto a data studio table report its filtering out empty values so my result set is smaller. Its only showing columns that have values in all dimensions. How can i stop this happening and also show the empty columns on the report?

Comment: Maybe pull the data into a Google Sheet first, where you can control what is happening a bit better, and then into Data Studio from there?

Comment: Where can i setup a google sheet?

Comment: docs.google.com. https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/big-query-and-google-spreadsheet-intergration/ looks useful re loading bigquery into a Sheet.

Comment: Hi @davey, were you able to make it work correctly?

Comment: No, it looks like data studio cant handle array value so the it needs to be flattened. Also Data studio doesn't have the concept grouping colasping and expanding.